# Set number of tables and rows

Tags: forms, visual-studio, rows

I am having my course project now,
and I am planing to create an application for soccer league,
but I am facing a problem. 
I want to create new league 
and there I want to create groups and teams in this way:

[image]

So, I want to create number of tables based on the (No. of Group) that will be entered by the user, for computing results among the teams inside each group.

And to set a (No. of teams /group), so based on that number rows in each group tables will be available.

I hope you got understand my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand....

Comment: Where you want to save data? In `Winforms` you can use `DataGridView` for displaying groups